# VBA how to vlookup/ index match where if target cell is blank, take another cell

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

i am trying to copy a date value to my sheet by index match from user excel file.
In my sheet - only 1 date column "plan date"
In user sheet- There are 2 date column "Action Updated date" and "Action Plan Date" (they are next to each other)

How do i express index match/vlookup that if user sheet "Action Updated date" is  blank, take "Action Plan Date"  otherwise (just like in  IFNULL() function in SQL which let me return an alternative value if an expression is NULL) ?

My actual code below for index match part which only work fine to match "Action Updated date"column  from user sheet to my sheet "Plan Date":

```
 table1 = mysheet.Sheets(1).Range("D3:D10")  'Style Number column from mysheet
 table2 = user.Sheets(i).Range("I3:DZ7")  ' DataRange of user template being copied
 table3 = user.Sheets(i).Range("I3:I7")   ' style number of user template
 table4 = user.Sheets(i).Range("I1:DZ1")  ' customer template column header range 
 Style_Row = mysheet.Sheets(1).Range("G3").Row
 Style_Clm = mysheet.Sheets(1).Range("G3").Column

 For Each cl In table1  'index match find if style number is matched between user template and mysheet, copy the data based on column header in table 

 On Error Resume Next
 myseeht.Sheets(1).Cells(Style_Row, Style_Clm) =Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cl, table3, 0), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Action updated date", table4, 0))  ' Plan Date

Style_Row = Style_Row + 1
Next cl
```

Comment: Add an IsEmpty test and branch the logic?

Comment: add some screenshots of your data, and explanation of `table2`, `table3` and `table4`

Comment: thank you for the feedback, I edited the question.